# Is there a way to stop a sqlite3 total() early when over a certain value?

Tags: sqlite, aggregate-functions

I have this `sample` table:

```
NAME SIZE
sam   100
skr   200
sss   50
thu   150
```

I want to do this query:

```
select total(size) > 300 from sample;
```

but my table is very big, so I want it to stop computing `total(size)` early if it's already greater than 300, instead of going through the entire table. (There are no negative sizes in my table.) Is there any way to do this in SQLite?

Comment: Do you just need a true or false result from your query?

Comment: Also, based on your question I imagine `size` is never negative?

Comment: I just wanted to know is it possible to add a condition like  total(size) > 300 and to come out with out scanning entire db after condition satisfies!

Comment: Always positive , never negative

Comment: Yes True/False would do

Comment: I edited your question to try to make it clearer. I hope I understood you correctly. If I edited wrong, please revert or change it.

Answer (score -2):

I've found a way to allow it to stop early, by using a window function, ***but*** unfortunately it makes it slower for a different reason. I hope someone else has a way to do this faster. To truly make it fast, you might need to create a custom aggregate function.

### Window function method

A normal aggregate function like `total()` will always add all of the rows its given, but you can use an aggregate [window function](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) instead to add only some of the rows:

```
select name, size,
       total(size) over (rows between unbounded preceding
                              and current row)
    from sample
```

will give you

```
sam|100|100.0
skr|200|300.0
sss|50|350.0
thu|150|500.0
```

in which the third column is a cumulative sum. You can see in this result that you'd like to stop this query once you see the `350`. You can do this by putting the above query into a subquery and using the `EXISTS` operator:

```
select exists(
    select 1
        from (select total(size) over (rows between unbounded preceding
                                            and current row)
                     as total_size
                  from sample)
        where total_size > 300)
```

This will filter the query to only the rows > 300, and then stop and return `true` (`1`) as soon as it finds one of them. If it never finds a row with that sum, it returns `false` (`0`).

**However:** this version can take longer than simply

```
select total(size) > 300 from sample
```

because it re-calculates the sum for each row, instead of just adding the next row's size to the running total.

Comment: *I've found a way to allow it to stop early...* none of your queries stops the execution when the desirable total is reached. Both queries calculate the total for each row of the table. The 2nd query will filter the rows after all the calculations are finished. This is why both queries should be significantly slower than the OP's query.

Comment: @forpas in testing, the query with `EXISTS` did indeed stop looking at more rows once it found one that matched the filter. This was evident by it running much faster when the end result was true, than when the end result was false, on the same size table.

Comment: EXISTS stops, but first all the totals for each row are calculated in the subquery.

Comment: @forpas but only for the rows needed to find the first match. Not needing to look at the other rows is what I meant by "stopping early".

Comment: @forpas per [the docs](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html), since SQLite 3.7.15 (2012-12-12) it can use co-routines instead of precomputing the entire table. Per `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` it is indeed using co-routines for this query.

Comment: What do you mean by *That's not what happens in SQL in general*? The condition of the WHERE clause is applied after the subquery calculates all the totals of each row of the table. Finally EXISTS checks if there is a row with the desired total.  As for the query plan you can see it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/EZV-NsYy for your code and the OP's code.